# Create VBA string array fastest method

Tags: strings, vba

My VBA has become *really* rusty but I need it for now for some data downloading.

This routine works but I'm certain that over the last 10 (at least) years something quicker/less code has surfaced to do the same thing. Any help appreciated. Please forgive my non-standard casing for VBA.

```
Public Function GetSymbols() As Variant

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(SymbolSheetName)

Dim tempRange, cCell As Range
Set tempRange = ws.Range(SymbolStartCell)
Set tempRange = Range(tempRange, tempRange.End(xlDown))

Dim symbolsArray() As String
Dim cntr As Integer
cntr = 0

For Each cCell In tempRange
    ReDim Preserve symbolsArray(cntr)
    symbolsArray(cntr) = cCell.Value
    cntr = cntr + 1
Next cCell
GetSymbols = symbolsArray
End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`As Integer` would be a problem with more than 32,767 cells - better to use `As Long` here.

`Set tempRange` in two consecutive assignments is suspicious, and the unqualified `Range` member call in the second expression will throw error 1004 whenever `ws` isn't also the `ActiveSheet` (unless that code is written in the code-behind for that particular worksheet... in which case both `SymbolSheetName` and `ws` are redundant; simply use the *code name* to refer to any worksheet that exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time).

`Dim tempRange, cCell As Range` is declaring `cCells` as a `Range`, and leaves `tempRange` as an implicit `Variant`.

Assigning a `Variant` cell's value to a `String` array element without validating the value would throw *type mismatch* errors if the cells contain any `#VALUE!` (or any other type of) worksheet errors; you should use `If Not IsError(cCell.Value)` to first validate whether the conversion can happen in the first place.

`ReDim Preserve` inside a loop is the killer; you're looking at a `Range`, and you know in advance how many cells you're looking at - you could size the array once and that would already be an improvement, but...

...you never need a loop to get a `Variant` array out of every cell in a `Range`:

```
Dim values As Variant
values = sourceRange.Value ' boom, values now contains a 2D variant array
```

If you want a single-dimension array and the range is small enough, you can use `Application.Transpose` to get it:

```
Dim values As Variant
values = Application.Transpose(sourceRange.Value)
```

Note that the way you get the cells you're looking for could lead to unexpected results if there are any empty cells in the range: by starting at the top and going `xlDown` from the first cell, your last cell is going to be at the first empty one. Usually we start at the bottom of the sheet instead, and go `xlUp`, making the last cell the first non-empty cell starting from the bottom, thus making fewer assumptions about the shape and content of the data - something like this:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = sheet.Range("A" & sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Lastly, in the last decade [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) appeared (a free & open-source VBIDE add-in I made with a couple of other VBA nerds) and can analyze your code and warn you about several things I noted in this answer.

Comment: Thanks. I use xlDown because the dataloading tool I am using will only produce usable rows. I wrote hundreds of macros using common types like Dim a,b,c as Range, never knew the first ones would turn Variant, somewhere I am sure I read you could do that that way. I wont get string errors, the range is a one column array of strings

Comment: ...why does the Transpose method create an array where the first index is 1 and not 0?

Comment: @dinotom the array comes from a `Range`, there's no row or column 0 in Excel, so Range arrays are 1-based so the indexes line up with cell rows/columns.

Comment: @dinotom you can declare multiple on one line like that in [vb.net](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement#declaring-multiple-variables) which is syntactically very similar and leads to confusing Google results, but not in VBA